# Get group owners - Sharepoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, office-365

I need a script to get all the group owners  of a site collection in Sharepoint Online.

Could you please help?

Thank you

Comment: What have you tried so far? This is a community for helping, not doing the job for you

Comment: $siteURL = "https://sitecollection.com"
$x = Get-SPOSiteGroup -Site $siteURL
foreach ($y in $x)
    {
        Write-Host $y.Title -ForegroundColor "Yellow"
        Get-SPOSiteGroup -Site $siteURL -Group $y.Title | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Users
        Write-Host
    }

Comment: The script above is the one I'm using to get all the groups and members from a site collection. Now I would like to know how can I get the group owners of each grou please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cann use the below CSOM Powershell script to fetch the site collection Groups Owners. Save the below code in .ps1 file.

make sure you have `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll` and `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll` keep this dlls in a location where you saved the .ps1 file.

You have to enter site collection url, username, password in script.

```
#Add - PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell  

$host.Runspace.ThreadOptions = "ReuseThread" 

Function Get-SiteGroup-Owners 
{ 
    param ($sCSOMPath,$sSiteUrl,$sUserName,$sPassword,$FileName) 
    try 
    {    
        $sCSOMRuntimePath=$sCSOMPath +  "\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll"         
        $sCSOMPathdll=$sCSOMPath +  "\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll"              
        Add-Type -Path $sCSOMPathdll          
        Add-Type -Path $sCSOMRuntimePath        

        #SPO Client Object Model Context 
        $spoCtx = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($sSiteUrl) 
        $spoCredentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($sUserName, $sPassword)   
        #$spoCredentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($sUserName, $sPassword)    # for on premise
        $spoCtx.Credentials = $spoCredentials        

        $web = $spoCtx.Web
        $spGroups =$web.SiteGroups

        $spoCtx.Load($web)
        $spoCtx.Load($spGroups)
        $spoCtx.ExecuteQuery() 

        Write-Host "Groups Count= $($spGroups.Count)"

        foreach($spGroup in $spGroups)
        { 
            $site = New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property @{
                                SiteUrl =$sSiteUrl
                                GroupName = $spGroup.Title
                                GroupOwner = $spGroup.OwnerTitle

                                } | Select  SiteUrl,GroupName,GroupOwner

          $site| Export-CSV ($sCSOMPath+"\"+$FileName+".csv") -NoTypeInformation -Append #-Encoding UTF8
        }       

        Read-Host -Prompt "file created Successfull..! in the following path $sCSOMPath, Press any key to close this window"

    } 
    catch [System.Exception] 
    { 
        Write-Host -ForegroundColor Red $_.Exception.ToString()    
        Read-Host -Prompt "Operation failed..! Press any key to close this and re run the script"
    }     
} 


$FileName= "SiteCollection_GroupOwners"          
$sSiteUrl = "Site Collection Url"  
$sUserName = "Enter User" 
$sPassword = ConvertTo-SecureString "Password" -AsPlainText -Force 

$scriptpath = $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path
$dir = Split-Path $scriptpath

Write-Host "Getting Site Collection group Owners"
Write-Host "-----------------------------------" 
Get-SiteGroup-Owners -sCSOMPath $dir -sSiteUrl $sSiteUrl -sUserName $sUserName -sPassword $sPassword  -FileName $FileName
```

Comment: Hello Suresh Bolineni, Many thanks for this! Is that a way to adjust the script in order to get all the members of each group as well? Thanks again!

Comment: Hi Peter smp..!. Yes you can get the list of all users from the group. You can give vote and select this an answer for this question. you raise one more question to get the users. I will Answer for you.

Comment: I've marked as an answer and I already voted. Many thanks. I'm going to make the question again. As requested, Is that a way to adjust the script in order to get all the members of each group as well? Thanks again!

Comment: Okay sure. Why I asked to do like this is other people also might search for getting group owners through script. If I modify this existing script. the answer is irrelevant for the question :)

Comment: Have raised the question ?

Comment: I have provided you the answer. pls check if it work. give vote up and mark it as an answer..! :)